# How to upgrade only an specific component of primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm currently working on a project and my team is using `primeng:^5.2.7`. I want to use a month picker using `<p-calendar view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy">`. But the problem is that `view=month` property is available in and after `primeng:6.1.6`. But I can't upgrade the entire `primeng` or else other components will start falling apart. I tried re-using code from their github [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/src/app/showcase/components/calendar) but I don't know the correct way to do that. `view=month` property is necessary because without that I'll get dates also which we dont want. I tried creating my own from the scratch but it doesn't looks professional as primeng. Here is the code I tried: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izrexx)

Is it even doable Or I'm wasting my and other's time. Please give me some direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade either whole primeng package or not anything.
One thing you could have done is, install upgrade version of primeng in separate folder and then copy  manually only required module.
But this would not work because that module might be using upgraded version of other packages, you can try it once though.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. But It'll not work I'm sure. Because older version of primeng is using javascript while new version of primeng is typescript. I checked their source code on github, there is a huge difference in structure and implementation.

Comment: There is a dependency on other newer packages also.